# Function is missing in type but required in type 'Props'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am passing a function to my `MapComponent`:

```
type Props = {
  results: SearchResult[];
  ...
  onDirectionsPress: (
    latitude: number,
    longitude: number,
    sitename: string,
  ) => void;
};

const MapTab = ({
  results,
  fuelType,
  searchDistance,
  addressName,
  onDirectionsPress,
}: Props) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    ...
    <MapComponent results={results} {...onDirectionsPress} />
  </View>
);
```

In my `MapComponent`, it is appearing as `undefined`, with the above error in TypeScript, How can I pass my function into my `MapComponent`?

```
type Props = {
  results: SearchResult[];
  onDirectionsPress: (
    latitude: number,
    longitude: number,
    sitename: string,
  ) => void;
};

const MapComponent = ({ results, onDirectionsPress }: Props) => {

  console.log('here', results, onDirectionsPress); <<< undefined 

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        minZoomLevel={2} // default => 0
        maxZoomLevel={15}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}>
        {Markers}
      </MapView>
      {showCard && <SearchResultCard {...resultProps} />}
    </View>
  );
};



export default MapComponent;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be passing `onDirectionsPress` with `onDirectionsPress={onDirectionsPress}` instead of `{...onDirectionsPress}`:

```
<MapComponent results={results} onDirectionsPress={onDirectionsPress} />
```